# Google App Engine Scheduler will not route requests to all available instances

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a running production environment (JAVA Spring MVC based) on Google App Engine. I've configured 1 resident F4 instance with 1 minimum instance. During normal times I have 2 instances, one resident and another dynamic. When there is more demand to the server **app engine fires a new instance but will not direct requests to it** and just keeps it running, sometimes for days:

[image: App Engine Instances]

- **Why doesn't app engine direct requests to these instances?**
- **Why doesn't app engine shut down these instances when they are idle for days?**

This is the configuration in the old console:

[image: App Engine Old Console]

**I did another test and configured 3 minimum instances** The instances fire, but still no requests are directed to them :( Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Same problem here!!! @Benny

Comment: @RenanFranca Did you find a solution? I still experience this issue :(

Answer (score 1):

Setting your maximum idle instances to 1 will force it to collect all but 1 of the idle instances.  The problem may be that it appears all the requests are going to the first 'dynamic' instance, the 'resident' instance is idle and therefore there is 1 'idle-dynamic' instance.   That strikes me as the likely logic that is producing the observed effects.

Comment: What you're saying makes since, but, from my understanding and experience, when you set the num of instance from 1 to automatic you don't get the resident instance. GAE just fire up instances whenever there is a need and they are all Dynamic. This can cause a delay for the first user until the first instance is fired up, which I want to avoid, this is why I set minimum 1 resident instance.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I can't be of more help.  If the UI has a 'feedback' link, you should submit some.  You might not get an answer but the devs might not know about a corner case in the LB computations that your app is triggering.  I know from other circumstances LB in low-QPS with periodic spikes can cause odd behavior in equations designed for a solid baseline flow.